# View is overlapped by another view in NestedScrollView with ConstrainLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_32"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/online_card_cv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_16"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_25"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin_8">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_8">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/online_card_rb"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_22"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_22"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_16"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/online_card_ll"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/online_card_ll"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/online_card_ll" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/online_card_ll"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_16"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingVertical="@dimen/padding_16"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/cards_iv"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/online_card_rb"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                            android:id="@+id/online_card_tv"
                            style="@style/OnlineCardTitleTextStyle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/online_card_title"
                            app:lineHeight="@dimen/default_text_size_28" />

                        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                            style="@style/OnlineCardSubTitleTextStyle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/online_card_now" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/cards_iv"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_80"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_20"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_16"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_visa_master"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/online_card_ll"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/online_card_ll" />

                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:id="@+id/online_card_expanded_info_cl"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/online_card_ll">

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/online_card_divider"
                            style="@style/ViewDividerStyle"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_16"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/cards_list"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/online_card_divider" />

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/cards_list_divider"
                            style="@style/ViewDividerStyle"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cards_list" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/read_more_tv"
                            style="@style/OnlineCardReadMoreTextStyle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_16"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_16"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_8"
                            android:text="@string/read_more"
                            android:visibility="visible"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cards_list_divider" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/additional_info_ll"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_21"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_16"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_10"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_8"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cards_list_divider">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/online_card_less_info_tv"
                                style="@style/OnlineCardReadMoreTextStyle"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/online_card_less_info" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/check_card_type_title_tv"
                                style="@style/OnlineCardBottomTitleTextStyle"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_4"
                                android:text="@string/online_check_card" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/check_card_type_info_tv"
                                style="@style/OnlineCardBottomDescriptionTextStyle"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_8"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_4"
                                android:text="@string/online_check_card_info" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/online_card_data_title_tv"
                                style="@style/OnlineCardBottomTitleTextStyle"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_4"
                                android:text="@string/online_card_data" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/online_card_data_info_tv"
                                style="@style/OnlineCardBottomDescriptionTextStyle"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_8"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_4"
                                android:text="@string/online_card_data_info" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/online_card_confirmation_title_tv"
                                style="@style/OnlineCardBottomTitleTextStyle"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_4"
                                android:text="@string/online_card_confirmation" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/online_card_confirmation_info_tv"
                                style="@style/OnlineCardBottomDescriptionTextStyle"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_8"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_4"
                                android:text="@string/online_card_confirmation_info" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/bank_account_cv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_16"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin_8">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_24">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/bank_account_rb"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_22"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_22"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_16"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/bank_account_tv"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bank_account_tv" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/bank_account_tv"
                        style="@style/OnlineCardTitleTextStyle"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_14"
                        android:text="@string/title_on_bank"
                        android:textAlignment="textStart"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/bank_account_rb"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/bank_account_divider"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_16"
                        android:alpha="0.5"
                        android:background="#000001"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bank_account_tv" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/iban_hint_tv"
                        style="@style/OnlineCardEditTextHintTextStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_16"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:text="@string/step7_iban_hint"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bank_account_divider" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                        android:id="@+id/step1_phone"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/height_edittext"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_16"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_2"
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext_with_border"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iban_hint_tv" />

                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
                        android:id="@+id/group"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:constraint_referenced_ids="step1_phone, iban_hint_tv, bank_account_divider" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/step7_next_btn"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/width_button_next"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/height_button_next"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_next"
            android:text="@string/next"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_green"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

When the part of the view has gone visibility, my screen looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, button is placed in the bottom and it's not overlapped by any other views. But when card is expanded, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, now button overlaps another card, and I need to place button under the card. So, how can I prevent existing behavior and place the button under all cards in the bottom? Thanks in advance, I will appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you want the button to be always visible (i.e. on top of the content, but you can still scroll the content) or all the way at the bottom (you have to scroll down to see the button)?

Comment: @Adrijan all the way at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

See below for an updated answer.

***Old***

I don't see the purpose of ConstraintLayout. You can remove that and place the button as last item in LinearLayout. The XML would then be like:

```
NestedScrollingView
    LinearLayout
        CardView ...
        CardView ...
        AppCompatButton
```

You can also use ConstraintLayout instead of LinearLayout, but I don't see the need for both.

This introduces a problem: the button is not at the bottom, when the content does not fill out the screen. For an easy fix, you can use ConstraintLayout with appropriate constraints.

***New***

I suggest you to use a ConstraintLayout. With it, you can achieve a flat layout hierarchy. You can use chains and vertical bias as such:

- Chain the first card to the top of your parent
- Chain the button to the bottom of your parent
- Chain the second card to the bottom of the first card and to the top of the button. Apply a vertical bias of 0.0.

The result:

[image: Card collapsed]
[image: Card expanded, button not visible]
[image: Card expanded, button visible]

And the simple code for the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#dddddd"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="First card" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="800dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/card1"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Second card" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="Button text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I have just seen that you expand the first card. This should still work.